# Having clause does not work

Tags: sql, group-by, having

I am beginner with SQL, I'm currently trying to use the HAVING CLAUSE but it does not work..

I have two tables :

1. tchat :
   [image: tchat table]
2. tchat_message :

[image: tchat_message table]

So I want the latest messages from the users.

**First :** I join the tables : `

```
select user_id, user_message, max(date_message) 
from tchat 
inner join tchat_message on tchat.id=tchat_message.user_id
```

here it's ok.

**Second :** I use the having clause :

```
select user_id, user_message, max(date_message) 
from tchat 
inner join tchat_message on tchat.id=tchat_message.user_id 
group by user_id 
having max(date_message) = date_message`
```

And here I have an error which says :

> Unknown column 'date_message' in 'having clause'

Does anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `having` clause incorrectly.  The following is closer to what you want:

```
select tm.user_id, tm.user_message, tm.date_message
from tchat t inner join
     tchat_message tm
     on t.id = tm.user_id inner join
     (select user_id, max(date_message) as maxdm
      from tchat_message
      group by user_id
     ) tmm
     on tmm.user_id = tm.user_id and tmm.maxdm = tm.date_message;
```

You don't need the `group by` in the outer query.  You also don't seem to need the `tchat` table (I've left it in in case you have additional columns in the `select` from that table).

Comment: There is nothing else easier?

Comment: @Mr.Smith67 See the other techniques in the duplicate question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: sometimes it's necessary to join to tables even if you aren't selecting columns from it if, for example, you only want to include records that have a match in the other table.